# No stack or heap when doing objdump

Tags: c, linux, unix, heap-memory, stack-memory

When I do objdump -x -d **name_of_some_c_executable**, I don't see the stack or the heap segments anywhere. Why?

```
**Clarification**:
objdump is defined as a program for displaying various 
information about object files.
```

What I mean by "name_of_some_c_executable":
I have a name.c, I do gcc name.c -o name, then I do objdump -x -d name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack and heap are runtime concepts, which have no pre-baked segment in the executable. Since they are just scratch space used dynamically, there's no reason why they should be present in the executable; they are created automatically at process (heap) or thread (stack) creation.